# How can I sum time in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

[image: DOWNTIME]

As you can see in the image I have a downtime report that shows downtime of the selected mill for the selected date. Now I want to add all the values in the `"Time Duration"` column and show it in a separate display near `"TOTAL TIME DURATION"`. For example, in the image, the selected dates are 17th March 2015 and 30th March 2015 and the selected mill is Raw Mill. the report shows the downtime for Raw Mill for the selected 13 days. I want to add all the time in the `"Time duration"` column for these 13 days and show it in a separate display near `"TOTAL TIME DURATION"`. The time format is HH:MM:SS. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

Use the following query :

```
SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(Time_Duration))) FROM TableName AS 'TOTAL TIME DURATION';
```

However, sometimes the total duration can exceed the maximum allowed time value, which is "838:59:59". So, you can generally use the following query which makes the calculation of the overflowed sum :

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(' hours and ',
  ((SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(Time_Duration)) DIV (TIME_TO_SEC('838:59:59')+1))*839), 
  (SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(Time_Duration)) MOD (TIME_TO_SEC('838:59:59')+1))) 
) 
FROM TableName AS 'TOTAL TIME DURATION'
```

This will give an output in the form :

```
3 hours and 3:45:05
```

You can also get the result in the exact format you want e.g. `6:45:05`, with the following custom query :

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(
    ':', 
    (SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(Time_Duration)) DIV 3600, 
    (SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(Time_Duration)) MOD 3600) DIV 60, 
    (SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(Time_Duration)) MOD 3600) MOD 60)
FROM TableName AS 'TOTAL TIME DURATION';
```

Comment: Didn't work. It shows the same value "838:59:59" even if the dates are changed.

Comment: I used it. MySQL query browser fetched more than 10000 rows almost all showing 0 hours and 00:00:00 while some rows show like this --> 0 hours and 00:00:12 or any value between 0 and 59 in the place of 12

Comment: please check again, I re-updated. I had forgotten the sum of all values in the second query.

Comment: It shows '31 hours and 657:16:23'. What does this mean?

Comment: It cannot be just 657 hours, because there are more than 10000 values in the table..

Comment: It meant (31*839) hours and "657:16:23". Please re-test the updated code (I added the final calculation of hours). I hope it's the last edit :P

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74094/discussion-between-ram-and-raptis-dimos).

Comment: Final comment : I also added a final query giving you the properly formatted result.

Comment: Sorry i didn't see this yesterday. The time duration column is VARCHAR(45).

Comment: Its working good for me. the time_duration column is VARCHAR.
Sample Query :
    SELECT employee_id, SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(time_duration))) as total_dur FROM time_tracker WHERE user_time BETWEEN '2017-11-26' AND '2017-12-02' AND FIND_IN_SET(employee_id,'584,452') GROUP BY employee_id

Answer (score 0):

**Steps**:

1. Fetch `time duration` values for given date range
2. Sum all the `time duration` values
3. Cast the result back to `time`, which is nothing but `total time duration`

**Example**:

```
mysql> SELECT CAST(SUM(time_duration) AS TIME) AS total_time_duration FROM (
    ->        SELECT CAST('01:08:00' AS TIME) time_duration
    ->        UNION
    ->        SELECT CAST('00:39:00' AS TIME)
    -> ) date_range_results;
+---------------------+
| total_time_duration |
+---------------------+
| 01:47:00            |
+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Comment: I can't add like this. Because the values keep changing when the dates are changed

Comment: @Ram: whether or not the input dates change, your scripting language should use the output of the `date range results` to sum the `time duration` to fill the `total time duration` box in your UI.

Comment: @Ram: For dates ranging only between `19` total duration should be `03:15:21`. Is the result correct or not?

Comment: Its right. But if the selected date is between Jan1 and March 30, the total duration is 88 days and there will be 88 values.. How will you add all of them?

Comment: What is the problem in summing of all those 88 values? Clarify the issue. You should actually post here, the query behind.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74087/discussion-between-ravinder-and-ram).

Comment: ->        SELECT CAST('01:08:00' AS TIME) time_duration
    ->        UNION
    ->        SELECT CAST('00:39:00' AS TIME)
    -> ) date_range_results;     I couldn't understand the query. Do i have to put all the values in select cast as time?